# Read QR Code via USB Camera in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, camera, qr-code

I'm developing a webApplication for an internal equipment rental service, in the company i'm working at. When lending and returning items, the user should be able to scan the items QR code. The website is run on a company server, which hosts websites that we only use internally.

I've developed code to decode and generate QR images, so I only need a way to show the QR scanner in the view (razor view engine) and to get the captured image from the scanner. I've already installed ZXing, but other recommendations like Touchless SDK, I'm unable to install.

I've searched the web for solutions, but I'm only finding WebForm application solutions and solutions for using smartphone/tablet cameras. I hope someone can point me in the right direction, to implement this functionality.

The scanner is this one: [Zebra Technologies Model DS457](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/scanners/fixed-mount-scanners/ds457.html)
There's a lot of user guides from them, but I cannot see how it's implemented in an MVC application.

**What I've tried:**
I've installed ZXing, but all guides are for webform applications
I've made a QR code generator and reader (read from images stored locally) using "QRCoder", which works fine.
I just need to find out how I can use ZXing or something else to get data from a scanner.

Comment: What did you try so far and what where your specific problems while solving your solution? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try searching for a Javascript (or WebAssembly) QR code scanner you can use in the frontend. Personally I'm using zxing

Comment: I’ve updated the post with what i’ve tried. I’ve installed ZXing but i can only find guides for webform applications, not MVC.